Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на html кнопку запускалась программа у человека на его компьютере
У нас есть локальная сеть. На каждом компьютере одинаковые пути ко всем программам. Есть сайт в этой локальной сети. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки на сайте, открывалась программа на компьютере этого пользователя (например word, .exe которого лежит по адресу С://Program files/Microsoft Word/word.exe)

вот был бы простор для мошенников, если бы такое было возможно.

Ну как-то же открывается телеграм по ссылке. Доступ к администрированию локальной сети также имеется.

так это не «открывается телеграм», это браузер у вас спрашивает, передевать ли обработку ссылки сторонней программе, зарегистрированной в данном компьютере для обработки подобных ссылок. как-то данный набор действий и требований не укладывается в «запуск произвольной программы, расположенной в произвольном месте файловой системы».

Это сделать невозможно. Но можно сделать так:

На компьютере есть программа, которая связывается с сервером по WebSocket
Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку, отправляется запрос на сервер
Тогда сервер отправляет программе команду
Программа выполняет нужное действие


А сможете поподробнее расписать как это делается с примером?

Нет _

можно еще в electron приложение сделать, и сайт изначально там открывать
